# print highest number to the right in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I would like to have an optimized java program to print the highest digits to the right of an array.
For eg: a[]={3,6,7,2,4,1}
output should be 7,4,1.
I wrote a program like below

```
class Rightlargest{
    public  static void main(String args[]){
        int a[]={1,3,2,4,5,2};
        int c[]=new int[20];
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=i+1;j<a.length;j++)
            {
                if(a[i]<a[j]){
                    a[i]=a[j];
                }
            }
            c[i]=a[i];
        }

        for(int i=0;i<c.length;i++)
        {
            if(c[i]!=c[i+1])
            System.out.println(c[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Even though I got the correct output, its throwing array out of bounds exception along with it.
Please advise.

Comment: Shouldn't it be 7,6,4? What is your criteria here? And `i+1<c.length`

Comment: `i+1` will allow the code to inspect for an element which is beyond the range of the array, when using `for(int i=0;i<c.length;i++)`.  You should consider using `for(int i=0;i<c.length - 1;i++)` instead, so you will check the second last position (`i`) agains the last position (`i + 1`)

Comment: The code needs some indentation, please!

Comment: If you only want to print the next highest value, there is no need change array values: `for(int index = 0 ; index < (array.length -1) ; index ++) {
   if(array[index] > array[index+1]) System.out.print(array[index]+" ");
  }
  System.out.println(array[array.length-1]);`

Comment: Thx madprogrammer.. that worked!!

Answer (score 0):

When *i* equals of *a.length-1*, *j* takes value *a.length* and that is the problem.

The array has length of 5 elements. It means the last element has index of 4

Answer (score 0):

**Fix for : ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException**

> i < c.length -1

```
for (int i = 0; i < c.length -1; i++) { // c.length -1

            if (c[i] != c[i + 1])
                System.out.println(c[i]);
        }
```

This will not exceed the array index out of bounds. Your loop was executing 1 index more than array length. 
As array **length->20** and **array index starts from 0,** **Your loop was iterating  (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)** **making last index to be checked as 21** which was out of array bounds.

**Working code with fix:**

```
public class RightLargest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int a[] = { 1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 2 };
        int c[] = new int[20];

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {

            for (int j = i + 1; j < a.length; j++) {

                if (a[i] < a[j]) {
                    a[i] = a[j];
                }
            }
            c[i] = a[i];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < c.length -1; i++) {

            if (c[i] != c[i + 1])
                System.out.println(c[i]);
        }
    }
}
```